# Operator theory curiosity

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm not an expert in operator theory... but i was wandering if there's some practical applications.

For example (the first one i came up with) compared to normal calculus techniques that usually the uni teaches to his student for solving differential equations does the operator theory give better tools for more complicated differential equations? or integral equations?

Could you provide example (simple to undestand possibly) where one technique is effective and the other isn't?

In terms of applications what's the difference (i.e. power?) among the three theory?

Comment: Operator theory (and certainly functional analysis) is absolutely essential to understanding some of the more complicated differential/integral equations.  Also, some proofs of facts you may take for granted (i.e. existence of a solution) may be proven using functional analysis techniques.

Comment: You might want to read as a simple example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Comment: but except existance of solution does such theory provide some particular technique (except numerical) for solving such class of equations?

Comment: Don't underestimate the importance of existence of solutions!

Comment: I probably should read some book on matter... i have a basic understanding of mathematical physics, but not specifically focused on functional analysis techniques... any suggestions? This one looks pretty nice https://books.google.it/books?id=wkBNXonCtPIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=unbounded+linear+operators+theory+and+applications&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TzSVVf7xB4as7Abnz4jIAw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=unbounded%20linear%20operators%20theory%20and%20applications&f=false but it doesn't have much excercises...

Comment: The inverse function theorem is a first nice application of operator theory. Basically it works due to Banach fixed point. Also that gives a way to construct such an inverse.

Comment: Dear @Lukkio. I see that, although you have already asked 7 question in this site and received answers in 6 of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly every Physical system has a linear regime where if you superimpose two small causes, the resulting effect is the superposition of the two separate causes, and if you double a small cause, then the effect is doubled. The state of the system is characterized by a collection of numbers (a vector) and the principle of superposition is stated in terms of linearity of a cause $\mapsto$ effect operator $L$:
$$
                     L(x+y) = Lx+Ly,\\
                     L(\alpha x) = \alpha Lx.
$$
So your question is broad, and I'm going to leave the answer just as broad, noting that the principle of superposition is linearity.

Time solution operators for time-invariant systems have an additional operator property: If you start with a state of the system $x$, and you evolve the state by $t$ seconds to obain $T(t)x$, then further evolving through $t'$ seconds gives $T(t')T(t)x$, which must be the same as starting with $x$ and evolving by $t+t'$ seconds, which gives
$$
                     T(t')T(t)x = T(t'+t)x.
$$
Time evolution has an exponential property, and that's hard to see except in an abstract operator theoretic framework. Even if the system varies with time, the operators $T(t',t)x$ from $t$ to $t'$ still obey a similar type of law: $T(t'',t')T(t',t)=T(t'',t)$.

Abstraction is a natural human activity that helps us isolate the essence of a problem, and gives us the ability to solve problems that we might never sort out without it. Operator Theory is a good language to express thoughts about Physical systems. It's no wonder that the language of Quantum Mechanics is Operator Theoretic.

I encourage you to consider numerical solution methods in terms of operators and states.

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean with "numerical solution in terms of operators and states"? Method like runge kutta? or finite element methods?

Comment: @Lukkio : Abstract operator that takes the data used in your algorithm and gives you new data after an application of the algorithm.

Comment: Out of curiosity it is possible to consider an interpolation scheme (polynomial for example) in terms of operators? if yes, how?

Comment: @Lukkio : So long as you have a deterministic algorithm, you have some kind of operator (maybe linear, maybe not) that takes data in some form $F_1$ to data in some form $F_2$ after application of the algorithm. Isolating some nice properties of the operator using properties of the algorithm is where you hope to gain traction.